# Strip <br> tag from text and replace it with a hard return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In WordPress, I'm pulling the value from one custom field and inserting it into another via ajax. However, when I pull in the value, it's showing the `<br />` tag in the field (a textarea). Is there a way to strip out the `<br />` tag before the value is inserted, and replace it with an hard return (as if you'd hit enter to put the text on a new line)?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
       jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

            var fields = response.split('_');

            // contact person
            $('#acf-field_55256bdcd0dba').val(fields[0]);

            // address (this text has <br> tags)
            $('#acf-field_552437ab1940b').text(fields[1]);

        });
```

This displays the address in the textarea as:

```
123 Elm Street<br />Anytown, USA 90210
```

And I'd like to display it as:

```
123 Elm Street
Anytown, USA 90210
```

Thank you!

Comment: A simple `.replace()` should work, assuming of course that an address can never correctly contain `<br />`.

Comment: Do you not have control over the content being sent by the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code also replaces things like `<br class="xyz" />` but doesn't match any other possible XML tags like e.g. `<brown>`:

```
fields[1] = fields[1].replace(/<br\s*(\s+[^>]+)*[\/]?>/gi, "\r\n");
```

I tested it against: `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br />`, `<br class="xyz">`, `<br class="xyz" />`

Comment: That worked, thank you. I will use this instead so I can cover all the variations of the <br> tag. What's the difference in using `/gi` versus `/g` ?

Comment: `g` is "greedy", so it matches all occurences and not just the first one (as in CezarisLTs answer). `i` is "(case) insensitive", so it matches both `<br>` and `<BR>`

Answer (score 0):

Simple replace of `br` to `\r\n` (new Line);

```
field[1] = fields[1].replace("<br/>","\r\n");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t78Loujs/

Comment: Thanks! It's almost working... but it's only removing the first <br />. I googled and found something about using the "g" in regex to replace all, but I'm not sure where to put the "g". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This code enabled me to replace all `<br />` tags with a newline:

```
fields[1] = fields[1].replace(new RegExp("<br />","g"),"\r\n");
```